# Sharepoint 2013 - adding the suitebar to a custom built page

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I've created a completely custom homepage in Sharepoint 2013 and it works fine (using custom HTML, CSS, JS, and Jquery Lib). I just need to know how to add the Sharepoint Suitebar to the top of the custom page.

I'm not using any type of Sharepoint template or master page template. I built my page like you would any other web page and uploaded my files into a directory within Sharepoint and then uploaded my custom page to the Site Pages directory and set it as home.aspx, which automatically makes it my homepage. Building a completely custom page like this is great, but I loose some built in features and components Sharepoint offers which I would like to use, the Suitebar being one of them.

My example HTML template here does not represent my actual custom homepage. I'm just linking this JSfiddle in hopes that someone will show me how/where to add in the Sharepoint Suitbar.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x1vcdeLx/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sharepoint Custom Homepage</title>

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="/sites/SiteAssets/css/reset.css">
<link href="/sites/SiteAssets/css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

<!-- BEGIN CREATIVE CONTENT -->
<div class="myContent">
    <div class="row-1-of-3"></div>
    <div class="row-2-of-3"></div>
    <div class="row-3-of-3"></div>
</div>
<!-- END CREATIVE CONTENT -->

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="/sites/SiteAssets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/SiteAssets/js/jquery-easing-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/SiteAssets/js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go and download the Sharepoint master page then search for the controls which are used for that suite bar. Put those controls in your page and it may display properly.

To get the name of the portion of the suite bar see image below
[image]

Comment: I did download a generic Sharepoint master page template and then grabbed the suitebar/nav bar from the HTML, but it broke my custom built page once I tried adding those pieces in. There is Sharepoint specific code in the HTML in the Header and Doc Type, and I have no idea what's needed and not needed.